# Can I remove a virus by flashing my android?

Tags: google-play-store

Guys my android is rooted, it was working fine . One day when I turned on my android many notifican like "setting has stoped" began to come . I was redirected to homescreen again and again . To remove this virus I reset my android tablet but even after factory data reset my problem was not solved . When I connected to wifi then automatically new apps were downloaded and I also noticed that wifi and unknown resourses were automatically enabled . I decided to reset my android again but there was again no improvement and some kind of porn apps became system apps . I also did hard reset but that also not worked . Now I am thinking to flash my android through SP Flash tool . Will it work?

Comment: It should work. By the way how did you root it?

Comment: I did it by the help of king root

Comment: so, was it like this from the time you rooted or after?

Comment: which device has the problem(which phone do you use?)

Answer (score 0):

All this behaviour can occur if the application you used to root your phone installs some kind of malware or you get a malware at a later point. You cannot remove this by a factory reset as it does not remove root or system apps and does not rewrite the system partition. Your only rescue here is to download [SP Flash Tool](https://spflashtool.com) and flash your system image, as flashing a system image rewrites your system partition and will remove every unwanted app, but you will lose root. If you want to root it again use [SuperSU](http://www.supersu.com/download) with [TWRP](https://twrp.me). It will not install any malware and your problem will get resolved.